# Orient DB Distributed Database

Tags: orientdb, hazelcast, multicast

I have been trying for hours now to set up a distributed database with Orient DB. I have followed their instructions here https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Tutorial-Setup-a-distributed-database.html but have had no luck. I am able to start a server on the first node. I then copy the directory and start a server in that copied directory, but the two nodes won't communicate with each other. They each just are acting as the first node. I tried using tcp instead of multicast in the hazelcast.xml file but that didn't seem to help. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If multicast was not enabled on your network then that would also prevent the new node joining the old one. tcp should work in most environments. What is the tcp config in your hazelcast.xml?

Comment: I changed the hazelcast.xml file on each install of OrientDB to:
`<tcp-ip enabled="true">
 <member>IP:2434</member>
        <member>IP:2434</member>
</tcp-ip>`

This didn't seem to work. Do those look like the correct ports to be using?

Comment: Are the two machines ping-able at those IP addresses and port? HC by default uses 5701 but since you have explicitly configured ports then your settings will be used. If the two machines are reachable with the configured settings then next step would be to share full Hazelcast logs from both nodes.

Comment: Ok thanks got it working using tcp.  Seems to be working well except one issue: If i start the server on machine1 then connect with machine2 everything works. If i then disconnect on machine1, ownership does not get transferred to machine2.  I am getting this error `[machine2] Cannot remove server 'machine1' because it is enlisted in 'servers' of the distributed configuration for database 'demodb'`. Any ideas?

Comment: That seems related to a demo application in Orient DB, looks like something is hard coded in “demodb”. I suggest check out it source code and/or ping OrientDB guys.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to setup a distributed environment that way, just copy the OrientDB folder *before you setup any nodes* or just download a fresh new installation.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to edit the hazelcast.xml file in order to make sure they can communicate? Or will two fresh installs of OrientDB automatically connect with each other?

Comment: You don't need to configure hazelcast as long as you launch the two OrientDB installs on the same machine.